# How to catch a specific exception in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception, google-drive-api

I need to catch **"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."** exception to do another action.
The problem is, I'm not sure how to recognize it.
Right now, I'm using

```
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

but the exception "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." appears inside the "InnerException" and the "Message", so no status code or anything.

How can I track this specific exception?

I am using GoogleDrive SDK if it's relevant.

Tried to use this:

```
catch (GoogleApiRequestException e) {
      if (e.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
        // Credentials have been revoked.
        // TODO: Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
    }
```

But e.HttpStatusCode was 0, so it didn't recognize it.

I guess I can use

```
if(ex.Message.Contains("401"))
```

But it's really bad

Comment: Why is it really bad to check message string ?, you could add "The remote server returned an error" to it too. Remember there isn't always a good, perfect, or standard way to do something. BTW you could use this for now and seek better solutions for future.

Comment: What is the InnerException type? If it is of a specific type then you can use that in a catch block.

Answer (score 0):

There has been an issue with google-api-dotnet-client code on version 1.7. If you are using this version I encourage you to update to latest.

If you look at this link: [Google.Apis.Email_Migration_v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435181/google-apis-email-migration-v2)
you will see that there has been a ticket on this bug.

Here is a tutorial and code-examples that shows how this error shall be taken cared of when the API is corrected:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors

If you still get the same problem, I also suggest the same solution to you problem to check for the 401 error in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleApiRequestException` class has a property `Code` not `HttpStatusCode`.
So you can check `Code` like below.

```
if(e.Code.Equals("401"))
```

I refered here.
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#catching_exceptions_with_client_libraries